# Make limb grow like tentacle

Tags: mesh, shape-keys

i would like to make a limb grow, like tentacle, the model has already an armature.I didnt find any reference- tutorials.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like, actually animate it growing out of the body?

Comment: Yes.but also keep the armature,or it would be better animate it, and then put the armature?

Comment: I would actually use the armature for that—try scaling the bones along their local Y-axis. If you need them to bend smoothly, you can increase the Segments value under Bendy Bones (Bone tab, Properties panel).

Comment: I tried it but did not work, I can not choose the armature parent, only the bone armature, and when I choose it, the armature is only modified it in edit and pose mode, which are doing nothing to mesh

Comment: It work, i was doing something wrong, you can post an answer if you want, i think there is also an other post, with the same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate the local Y-axis of the bones (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>).